# Calling multiple configuration/variable files into Ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I have two configuration files (accountinfo.json and settingsinfo.json) which needs to be called into the playbook. Is there a way to call multiple configuration files during the Ansible playbook execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: "*Is there a way to call multiple configuration files during the Ansible playbook execution?*"

A: Yes. It is. Either use [vars_files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files)

```
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - accountinfo.json
    - settingsinfo.json
  tasks:
```

, or [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task)

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        files: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - accountinfo.json
        - settingsinfo.json
```

See:

- [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)
- [ansible vars_files vs include_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253879/ansible-vars-files-vs-include-vars)

Comment: Json files and playbook should be under the same directory??

Comment: It's up to you where you put the files. See recommended layouts in [Best practicies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices). It's not mandatory. [Special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) like "playbook_dir", "role_path", or "inventory_dir" can be used to create dynamic paths. It's very flexible. Structure the inventory and fit it to your architecture and needs. You might want to start with the question "Where does the configuration data come from?"