# Upload var_files based on a value or ignore if not exist

Tags: ansible

I have a small playbook that is using variables based on a file.

`Main.yml` the file will always exist while `second.yml` might exist.

1. Is it possible to configure the playbook to continue in case `second.yml` file does not exist?
2. If I will add to the `main.yml` the value of `Additional_file: yes`, Can I configure the playbook to load `second.yml` only in case `Additional_file value = yes`

Comment: `var_files`, being a directive, won't allow you that. The `include_vars` module on the other hand will. This is extensively covered in this question: [ansible vars\_files vs include\_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253879/ansible-vars-files-vs-include-vars)