# How can I import a text file containing the names of users in Ansible?

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, redhat

I am currently working with Ansible and I wanted to see if I could import a text file containing the names of users I plan to create and loop it in.

```yaml
---
- name: Create users thru loop
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
- name: Create users
  user:
    name: ”{{ item }}””
  loop:
      - jerry
      - kramer
      - eliane
```

Answer (score 2):

> *... import a text file containing the names of users ...*

One approach can be to use [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) in order to load variables from files, dynamically within a task.

```yaml
~/test$ cat users.yml
---
users:
 - alice
 - bob
 - charlie
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: users.yml
      name: included

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ included.users }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=alice) =>
  msg: alice
ok: [localhost] => (item=bob) =>
  msg: bob
ok: [localhost] => (item=charlie) =>
  msg: charlie
```

**Further Reading**

- [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html)
- [Ansible: `vars_files` vs `include_vars`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53257820/6771046)
- [4 steps to create Linux users from a CSV file with Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-create-users-csv)
- [Ansible: Create users from CSV](https://serverfault.com/a/850523/448950)